# Connecting Mysql and qt?

Tags: mysql, database, qt, ubuntu, connection

I'm having some difficulties connecting a program I'm building with qt. And once I do that, how do I get the database to work with a table widget?

I should probably let you know that I don't know where to begin other than I made the database with libreoffice base.

Comment: You're not giving us much information to go on. But if you're looking for how to connect Qt to MySQL, you don't need to worry. This is already taken care of by [QSqlDatabase](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqldatabase.html)

Answer (score 3):

Qt provides the model/view framework which is a very flexible tool for presenting data in tables, trees, or lists. so the model you need to use is `QSqlTableModel`.

First create a QSqlDatabase instance, and connect to the database

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("my_database");
db.setUserName("username");
db.setPassword("password");
if(!db.open())
    QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error","Unable to connect to the database");
```

then create the model

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(parent,db);
model->setTable("students");
model->select(); //< fetch data
```

and finally tell the table to diplay data from this model

```
QTableView *table = new QTableView;
table->setModel(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

Under Qt's help system, take a look at Examples, go to SQL, and pick the Table Model Example. You'll find it's not that hard to use MySQL with Qt. (You may have to hand-compile the qtmysql driver; on my system it's in /QtSources/4.7.3/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/mysql.pro. Just qmake/make/make install. Good luck and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

1. add QT +=Core sql into .pro
2. download libmysq.dll and add to Qt-> Qt 5.3.0 -> mingw482_32 -> Plugins -> sqldrivers
3. create new Qt console file
4. add this line to main.cpp

.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("");
db.setDatabaseName("sim");

if(db.open())
{
    qDebug() << "connected " << db.hostName();
}else{
qDebug() << "Connection FAILED.";

}
return a.exec();
}
```